# IOS pass UIbuton to method as reference

Tags: ios, objective-c

In view.h I declare

```
@property (retain, strong) UIButton *btn;
```

In view.m I first have:

```
@synthesize btn;
```

and then in implementation I have this call to a method in another class:

```
[self.view addSubview:[otherclass getTestBtn:btn]];
```

After this line, in my view.m, I try to log the text in the button like this:

```
NSLog(@"btn.titleLabel.text =  %@", btn.titleLabel.text);
```

Unfortunately the logs says:

```
btn.titleLabel.text = (null)
```

In the other class.m I implemented the method this way:

```
btn              = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 340, 100, 25)];
[btn setTitle:@"HELLO" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
return btn;
```

In the simulator I see that the button shows the text "Hello". But from view.m the text in the button don't seem to be accessible. Why?
Im afraid that the button that is passed from view.m to other class.m is not passed by reference. And hence the button in view.m is not affected by the method in other class. Is that the reason? If yes: how to pass the button as reference? I tried with & character. But the editor shows errors.

Comment: Change declaration: `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btn;`

Comment: It s still showing NULL in debug area.

Comment: Please provide a more complete code sample. Your existing example references `btn2` which is not defined as far as we can see. We cannot help you without an accurate view of what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, code should look good now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the button returned from the other class then you need to assign it to your property -

```
self.btn = [otherClass getTestBtn];
[self.view addSubView:self.btn];
```

Also, you should `strong` rather than `retain` as @dimimpou said and you don't need `@synthesize` any more unless you want to use a specific backing variable name.

Comment: Yes I guess it is the simplest way to do it. The thing is that I actually from view.m ask otherclass.m for another view *that contains the button*. So it is not really doable right now. I would need to change the design of the code. I wanted the other class to take care of all the graphical elements and let view.m handle the clicks on button etc.

Comment: It sounds like you want a delegation pattern with `view.m` acting as the delegate for the objects in `otherclass`. But the code in your question doesn't assign anything to the `btn` property which is why it is nil.

Comment: Is it about passing view.m as a delegate to the method in otherclass?

Comment: A delegation pattern would enable otherClass to call methods in view.m in response to events - it is a commonly used pattern in ObjectiveC and iOS.